git-credential-store not supplying credentials to git client
I have a local git server, and all I really want is to avoid typing in a password for every git operation (fetch, push, etc.). My "remote" git server is on my-nas.local, with SSH running on port 22322 using user account gituser.
Okay, no problem, I think.. just use this on my MacBook:
git credential-store --file ~/.git-credentials get

..and add my credentials via git credentials fill:
git credential fill
protocol=ssh
host=my-nas.local
username=gituser
password=My-S3cr3t-P4ssw0rd

And I double check my ~/.git-credentials file:
% cat ~/.git-credentials
ssh://gituser:My-S3cr3t-P4ssw0rd@my-nas.local

But every git operation still prompts me for the password.
What did I miss? A .gitconfig entry perhaps?

Git credentials store is not used for SSH protocol, it's used only for HTTP(S). For SSH protocol use keypair authentication: generate a keypair, upload public key to your NAS (use ssh-copy-id), check with ssh gituser@my-nas.local
In answers for this question you can find detailed instructions.
Search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bssh%5D+Permission+denied+publickey
